# Laravel - How to query when you have a many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have two models: Product and Size. One product may have many sizes and one size may have many products that have that size. I made many ot many relationship between them with a product_size pivot table. Now I need to query all products that have a certain size. Here is my code:

Edit:

```
    $minPrice = $request['min'];
    $maxPrice = $request['max'];
    $colors = $request['color'];
    $sizes = $request['size'];

    if (count($request->all()) != 0) {

        $query = Product::with(['sizes' => function($query) use($request) {
            $sizeArray = $request->get('size');
            $query->whereIn('sizes.size', $sizeArray);
        }]);

        if(isset($minPrice) && isset($maxPrice)) {
            $query->whereBetween('price', array($minPrice, $maxPrice));
        }

        if(isset($colors)) {
            $query->whereIn('color_id', $colors);
        }

        $products = $query->get();
    }
```

Here are my models:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function color()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Color');
    }

    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Size', 'product_size')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Size:

```
class Size extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_size')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<form id="filterOptions" method="get" action="{{ URL::current() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-color">Filter</button>

    <div class="clearfix space20"></div>
    <h5>Color</h5>
    <ul class="color-list">
        @foreach($availableColors as $color)
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="{{ $color->id }}"><a href="#"><span class="{{ $color->name }}"></span> {{$color->name_bg}}</a></li>
            {{ $color->name }}
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix space20"></div>

    <h5>Price</h5>
    <div id="slider-container"></div>
    <p>
        <span class="{{--pull-right--}} sc-range">
            <input class="pull-left" name="min" type="text" id="min" style="border: 0; color: #333333; font-weight: bold;"/>
            <input class="pull-right" name="max" type="text" id="max" style="border: 0; color: #333333; font-weight: bold;"/>
        </span>
    </p>

    <div class="clearfix space30"></div>
    <h5>Size</h5>
    <ul class="size-list">
        @foreach($availableSizes as $size)
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="{{ $size->id }}">{{ $size->size }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</form>
```

This is my current code. Everything works besides querying the sizes. It doesn't output any error. However it doesn't query the products according to the size.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many documents how many to many relations can be defined. Do the docs help? Another link here can help: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2016/04/06/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/

Comment: I have already set-up the relations and everything works. However I don't know how to query products according to size (Size model where the relation is many to many)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a combination of "[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)" and the [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) method:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('size', function ($query) {
    // In the following line, replace "name" with the appropriate
    // field that relates to $request['size'].
    $query->whereIn('name', (array)$request['size']);
})->get();
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Since I am doing more queries I think it is a little bit more complicated. Could you please update your answer to work with my code?

Comment: @Codearts If I understand correctly, you just need to chain another `->whereHas()` for the "color" relationship before the final `->get()`.

Comment: Finally got it working the way I wanted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $criteria = array(
        "prices" => array(
            $request['min'] ? $request['min'] : false,
            $request['max'] ? $request['max'] : false
        ),
        "colors" => $request['color'] ? $request['color'] : false,
        "sizes" => $request['size'] ? $request['size'] : false
    );



    $products = Product::with(['sizes' => function ($query) use ($criteria) {

        if($criteria['sizes']) {
            foreach ($criteria['sizes'] as $size) {
                $query->where('size', '=', $size);
            }
        }

    }])->where(function ($query) use ($criteria) {

        if($criteria['colors']) {
            foreach ($criteria['colors'] as $color) {
                $query->where('color_id', '=', $color);
            }
        }

        if( $criteria['prices'][0] && $criteria['prices'][1] ) {
            $query->whereBetween('price', $criteria['prices'] );
        }

    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough and I could be wrong, but anyways. You may try this. So, first of all, you don't need to use something like the following:

```
$minPrice = $request['min'] ? $request['min'] : null;
```

Instead, you can just use something like the following:

```
$minPrice = $request->min;
```

This will return a value if exists otherwise, it'll return `NULL` value. So, in your example, you may simply use:

```
$minPrice = $request->min; // Or  : $request->get('min', 'default value if null');
$maxPrice = $reques->max;  // Also: $request->input('max');
$colors = $request->color;
$sizes = $request->size;
```

But, in your case, since you are conditionally building the query depending on the inputs so you may use something like: `$request->has('String|Array')`, for example, let's try the following approach to build the query conditionally:

```
// Begin query: No need to check for the size, query will work if
// there is no size available, hence 'sizes' will an be empty collection
$query = Product::with(['sizes' => function($query) use($request) {
    $sizeArray = $request->get('size'); // Make sure it's an array
    $query->whereIn('size', $sizeArray); // if null, the query'll work
}]);


// Now check min & max and make query
$minAndMaxKeys = ['min', 'max'];
if($request->has($minAndMaxKeys)) {
    // This'll return, ex: ['min' => 10, 'max' => 20]
    $minAndMaxArray = $request->only($minAndMaxKeys);

    // Build query using min and max values from the array
    $query->whereBetween('price', array_values($minAndMaxArray));
}

// Now check colors and make query
if($colors = $request->get('colors')) {
    $query->whereIn('color_id', $colors);
}
```

Now, just execute the query:

```
$result = $query->get();
```

The `$result` will contain a collection of `Product` model with matching `price` range and `colors` wherein each `Product` model will contain related sizes (collection of Size model) or an empty `sizes` collection if there was no matching found.

If you only want to get result only when sizes are available then use `whereHas` with the `with`. Check the other answer for that.

It's not possible to answer accurately because your question has less information. Check the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2) documentation for better understanding.

Comment: Everything works besides the sizes query. It just doesn't do anything. What information do you need more to fix my problem?

Comment: What you get from `$request->sizes` and how it's related to products table?

Comment: I get the ids of all chosen sizes (checked checkboxes). It is not related. But there is a pivot table called product_size with id, product_id and size_id. With this and belongsToMany I create a many to many relationship.